# HttpContext is null for MVC controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a pretty vanilla controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationUserManager _applicationUserManager;

    public HomeController()
    {
        _applicationUserManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }
}
```

However, when I hit it the `HttpContext` it's null.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`HttpContext` is being referenced in the constructor.  There isn't an `HttpContext` here as they're only created when there is a request.

Moving `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();` to an action solves the problem.